# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality using a particular result from orthonormal sets

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, orthonormal

Let {$e_1, ... , e_k$}  be an orthonormal set in a finite dimensional real inner product space $V$. If $ v \in V$, I have shown the following result:

$\sum_{i=1}^{k} |\langle v,e_i\rangle|^{2} \leq ||v||^{2} $

I am trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality based on this property.

There exists an orthonormal basis {$e_1,...,e_n$} of $V$ and for $v,w \in V$ we therefore have that there exists $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ie_i = v$  and $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_ie_i = w $.

Then $|\langle v,w\rangle| = |\langle v,\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_ie_i\rangle| \\  \qquad \qquad \quad = |\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i\langle v,e_i\rangle| \\ \qquad \qquad \quad $

I get stuck from here though.

Comment: It is far simpler to prove Cauchy-Schwarz directly, rather than having anything to do with orthogonal bases...

Comment: Sure, but I am wanting to prove it using this property specifically for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From you last line, apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$\mid<v,w>\mid^2\le \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^kb_i^2\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k<v,e_i>^2 \le  \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^kb_i^2||v||^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k <w,e_i>^2||v||^2 \le ||w||^2||v||^2\implies \mid<v,w>\mid\le ||v||||w||.$

Comment: Hm where does that first inequality come from

Comment: It is the standard Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It's like an opener.

Comment: But here I am trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: Good question. The CS inequality has several versions. Which one do you want to prove?

Comment: This is the inner product for real f.d. vector spaces, the one used in your proof is the special case where the inner product is the dot product right? Does this not make the proof circular?

Comment: Not circular, but just used a different tool ( provide by you ) to prove the norm version of the CS inequality.

Comment: So I'll have to prove that on top of this proof too, in order to justify that step?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: -1: using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality makes little sense.

Comment: It's not using CS to show CS but rather to striving to make some progress in the current work of OP. Also, the current level of OP is around the elementary dot product and not advanced such as C*-algebra or any thing beyond the elementary level.